# How can I pass XML data in body with HttpPlugin ionic2

Tags: xml, ionic2

I am calling one service which accept `XML` request and response also in `XML` so for that I have done below code

```
let xmlBody = '<ServiceRequest>' +
        '<SRNumber>123456' +
        '</SRNumber>' +
        '</ServiceRequest>';


    this.httpPlugin.setHeader('authorization', "Bearer " + token);
    this.httpPlugin.setHeader('content-type', "application/xml");
    this.httpPlugin.post('https://xxx.test.server/Service', xmlBody, {}).then((response) => 
{

})
```

Based on above request its always return with error **status:500**

I think my body not reaching to server

Any help how can I request `XML` body through HttpPlugin ?

Comment: is it a SOAP request?

Comment: No not SOAP its normal service

Comment: have you tested server side using a rest client ? 500 error basically means your server threw an error

Comment: Yes I have tested it through Postman with XML request and its working as expected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484441/angular2-posting-xml-type-request-data-using-http try header "content-type" "text/xml"

Comment: No luck same error 500 :(

Comment: the request looks fine as far as I can see.. maybe log server side to see any errors if possible

Comment: server side log is not possible as its 3rd party client service and I have checked without passing body and its showing XML response so the problem is only with Body not passing properly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of R&D finally I got solution to pass `XML` in my request check below code for more detail :

```
          let headers = {
            "Content-type": 'application/xml',
             "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
          };

          let xmlBody =
          '<ServiceRequest>' +
          '<CaseNumber>' + caseNumber +
          '</CaseNumber>' +
          '</ServiceRequest>'

          this.httpPlugin.setDataSerializer('json');

         this.httpPlugin.post('https://test-dev.com/Service', xmlBody , headers).then((response) => {
          console.log("XML Response : ",JSON.stringify(response.data));
          xml2js.parseString(response.data, function (err, result) {
            if(result){
              resolve(result);
            }else{
              reject(err);
            }
            console.log("XML parser success:",result);
            console.log("XML parser error:",err);
            });
```

In above code we need to follow 2-3 step which will lead to `XML` request successfully send on server.

**1st :** Set header in `JSON` formate not use setHeader method of plugin.

**2nd :** Set `XML` body with add new line in it as above.

**3rd :** This point is kind of patch without this code will not work

```
  this.httpPlugin.setDataSerializer('json');
```

By this we can successfully get response on `XML` based API.

**Help source :** https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http/issues/34

> Note : XML parsing use xml2js plugin

hope this will help some one who is facing same issue like me.