# How do I POST a XML body in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm currently working on an Ionic application that is supposed to make REST API calls with XML as the body. I'm having trouble getting the call to actually post with XML. This is my LoginProvider. I'm using DOMParser to parse my data to XML before posting it to the API.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Constants from '../../services/constants';

@Injectable()
export class LoginProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }

  postLogin(username : String, password : String) {
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let xmlString = "<alm-authentication>  <user>" + username + "</user> <password>" + password + "</password> </alm-authentication>";
    let doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "application/xml");
    console.log(doc);

    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.post(Constants.API_ENDPOINT + "/authentication-point/alm-authenticate", doc, {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

But when i inspect the post request in Google Chrome i get the following:

[image]
The request payload seems to be in JSON instead of XML. How can i make it actually send the XML file?

I have already tried changing the body to a xml string instead of the file, and changing the content type but this still gave the same error.

I'm using Ionic-angular version 3.9.2 with angular version 5.0.3

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48420473/how-can-i-pass-xml-data-in-body-with-httpplugin-ionic2?noredirect=1&lq=1) might helpful.

Comment: @MuhammadSaifuddin that thread seems to be using Cordova. Since i'm not using that, i'm hoping for a different solution.

Comment: `.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` — That's a **response** header, it has no business being on a request header. Remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> let doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "application/xml");
> ```

`doc` is an object representing the DOM of an XML document.

> ```
> http.post(Constants.API_ENDPOINT + "/authentication-point/alm-authenticate", doc, {headers: headers})
> ```

You are passing `doc` as an argument to `http.post`.

Since you are passing an object, Angular is trying to convert it to JSON.

If you are encoding the request payload yourself (i.e. you don't want Angular to convert it to JSON) then you need to pass **a string**.

Pass `xmlString` instead of `doc`.